# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on UITextAttributeFont (Invalid iOS version)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm using setTitleTextAttributes to change the font on a `UISegmentedControl` as follows.

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0f];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:UITextAttributeFont];
[self setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];</pre></code>
```

This works fine in the simulator, but crashed when running on an iPad.  The bad access fault occurs on creation of the dictionary and I used an NSLog statement to verify that UITextAttributeFont is generating the fault.

Any ideas what the problem is here or if there is an alternative method to set the font?

**EDITED**

I just realized the iPad is running iOS 4 (I believe this is supported on iOS >= 5).  What is the best way to test for version support?

Based on Dirty Henry's suggestion, the correct implementation is as follows.

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setTitleTextAttributes: forState:)]) {
      UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0f];
      NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: font, UITextAttributeFont, nil];
      [self setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: check to make sure `font` is not nil before going into the `dictionaryWithObject` method.

Comment: Added an if(font != nil) just to be certain.  No joy.  Any other ideas?

Comment: No, not yet... to my eyes it looks like you're doing the right thing. Try creating a dictionary a different way... e.g.: `dictionaryWithObjects:andKeys:` or `alloc` + `init` (making sure to release it later if you're not using ARC).  See if the crash still happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your iPad running iOS 5.0 or later? (UITextAttributeFont has been introduced in this version). (i don't see anything wrong with your code either)

Comment: Nope, I just realized this myself. What's the best method to test for support?

Comment: You should test respondsToSelector: on your UISegmentedControl with setTitleTextAttributes:forState: to see if it's supported. (cf. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html)

Comment: Welcome. And on your updated question, you can even put the boldSystemFontOfSize: inside the if() condition ;)